# Java view of JScrollPane only showing up half the time

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, repaint

Just started using Swing and I chose null layout because I came from the world of Flash and I'm used to specifying every single pixel and size. I'll pick up on layouts later.

The problem right now is the JTextArea that is the view of the JScrollPane only appears half the time I run the program. I can't select it or type in it because it's not there. The pane appears 100% of the time though. If I hit tab a couple times the focus will land on the text area then it'll appear.

I've removed a huge chunk of the code that has nothing to do with the problem. That's why some of the code looks weird like the MenuItemSelected.

There are so many repaints at the end of the PathsPanel's constructor because it was my "last ditch" effort to fix this problem because I read in many threads that repaint usually fixes things not showing up.

Also if I comment out the setText above the repaints, the text area will show up even less often.

DayPlanner

```
public DayPlanner () {
    //win is a JFrame
    win.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    win.setLayout (null);
    win.setResizable (false);
    win.setVisible (true);

    MenuItemSelected ("Paths");
    win.repaint ();
}

public void MenuItemSelected (String command) {
    ChangePanel (PathsPanel.class, pathsPanel);
}

private void ChangePanel (Class panelClass, Component ref) {
        activePanel = new PathsPanel (this);
        pathsPanel = (PathsPanel) activePanel;

        win.add (activePanel);
        win.repaint ();
    }
}
```

PathsPanel

```
public PathsPanel (DayPlanner parent) {
    //extends JPanel
    this.parent = parent;

    setLayout (null);
    setBounds (0, 0, 500, 500);

    txtMessages = new JTextArea ();
    txtMessages.setOpaque (true);
    txtMessages.setBackground (Color.RED);

    JScrollPane scpMessage = new JScrollPane (txtMessages, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    scpMessage.setBounds (0, 0, 500, 500);

    txtMessages.setText ("AWD");
    txtMessages.repaint ();
    scpMessage.repaint ();
    repaint ();
}
```

I bet this has something to do with not using a LayoutManager!

Comment: 1) *"I bet this has something to do with not using a LayoutManager!"*  Quite possibly.  2) Make sure all GUI creation & updates are done on the EDT. 3) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: What happens when it is not displayed, a blank space?

Comment: @AndrewThompson you're correct with #2.

Comment: @MouseEvent It just displays the JScrollPane with nothing inside.

Comment: In your `PathsPanel` constructor, I can't see where you `add()` the `txtMessages`?